# Is there a way to download the iphoto 9.6 update/installer for an offline upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, photos.app

upgrading my mom's mac to yosemite - her internet connection is slow.  Would like to put the updater/installer on a USB drive.

on the apple site, there are direct downloads for older versions of iphoto, but not the latest.

I was also able to download yosemite and put it on a usb drive.  but not iphoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the new iPhoto itself on a USB drive, and just replace the file in Applications (after taking the necessary backup precautions, of course). It should work fine.

Source: My own experience, having upgraded a computer to Yosemite with the sole available wifi network having a finite amount of data.

Comment: do you mean, copy the iphoto.app dir from the applications directory of another mac that has the latest?  Sounds like a plan... though I wonder if apple has different versions for different hardware editions (late 2012 MBPr vs. 2009 MBP 13)

Comment: @marathon My experience consisted of giving a 2012 MBA's iPhoto to a [back in the days of still having a disk drive; I don't know the exact year] iMac. Hardware shouldn't be an issue.